# How to inject a property into a custom ActionFilterAttribute using StructureMap?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, structuremap, custom-action-filter

Injection correctly work in my solution except for customs ActionFilterAttribute.
Here is an example : I'd like to populate the property UserModel using injection into the following ActionFilterAttribute.

```
public class UserFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public IUserModel UserModel { get; set; }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext actionContext)
    {
        // here is my problem : this.UserModel is always null

        base.OnActionExecuting(actionContext);
    }
}
```

Global.asax.cs :

```
private void ConfigureDependencies()
{
    Guid userId = new Guid();

    // Register models
    IContainer container = new Container(cfg =>
    {
        cfg.Scan(scan =>
        {
            scan.TheCallingAssembly();
            scan.WithDefaultConventions();
        });

        cfg.For<IFilterProvider>().Use<StructureMapFilterProvider>();
        cfg.For<IUserModel>().Use<UserModel>().Ctor<Guid>().Is(userId);
        cfg.SetAllProperties(x => { x.OfType<IUserModel>(); });

    });

    ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new StructureMapControllerFactory(container));
    DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new StructureMapDependencyResolver(container));
}

protected void Application_PostAuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.ConfigureDependencies();
    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
}
```

FilterConfig.cs :

```
public class FilterConfig
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
        filters.Add(new UserFilterAttribute());
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2010/05/03/dependency-injection-in-asp-net-mvc-filters/ ?

Comment: setting `[SetterProperty]`(structuremap property injector) attribute on `public IUserModel UserModel { get; set; }` migh work.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `IController` to your *scanner*

```
cfg.Scan(scan =>
{
    scan.TheCallingAssembly();
    scan.WithDefaultConventions();
    scan.AddAllTypesOf<IController>();
});
```

Comment: Injection in my controllers already work. However, I tested your suggestion "just in case" but it doesn't change anything.